# How to force pythons format method to place values as they are evaluated

Tags: python, datetime, string-formatting

I need to figure out the accounting year based on a date, while I am using the format method with datetime.datetime object it is generating the unexpected results for the same type objects with different values

Below is my code.

```py
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.strptime('2019-03-03','%Y-%m-%d')
## Below line is killing my mind as it is resulting 2019-2018
print('{}-{}'.format(dt.year, (dt.year+1)%100 if dt.month > 3 else dt.year-1,(dt.year)%100))
# This will produce the result 3 2019 19
print(dt.month, dt.year, (dt.year)%100)

dt = datetime.strptime('2019-04-04','%Y-%m-%d')
# But the below line is working fine as it is resulting 2019-20
print('{}-{}'.format(dt.year, (dt.year+1)%100 if dt.month > 3 else dt.year-1,(dt.year)%100))
# This will produce the result 4 2019 19
print(dt.month, dt.year, (dt.year)%100)
```

I am expecting the result

```
2018-19 if dt = datetime.strptime('2019-03-03','%Y-%m-%d')
2019-20 if dt = datetime.strptime('2019-04-04','%Y-%m-%d')
```

I am not able to figure out the problem with the code.

Comment: So... what exactly is the expected result?

Comment: And, please never post screenshots of text. Just copy-paste it here and format it accordingly, the screen is useless for debugging purposes

Comment: `(dt.year+1)%100 if dt.month > 3 else dt.year-1` returns `(dt.year+1)%100` (two digits) or `dt.year-1` (four digits). Not quite sure what else you're expecting…?

Comment: also you have two formatting brackets `'{}-{}'` but passing 3 arguments to it

Comment: Thanks to Devesh noticing the brackets and number, I think you just need parentheses: `'{}-{}'.format( (dt.year, (dt.year+1)%100) if dt.month > 3 else (dt.year-1,(dt.year)%100) )`? Because you want your `if` to work on both values, not just one.

Comment: @h4z3 I don't think returning a tuple `(dt.year-1,(dt.year)%100)` makes a lot of sense either.

Comment: @deceze It would be either (dt.year, (dt.year+1)%100) or (dt.year-1,(dt.year)%100). So the string would be "2019-20" or "2018-19". Makes a lot of sense. It would need unpacking, though. I will post a changes thing as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
## Below line is killing my mind as it is resulting 2019-2018
print('{}-{}'.format(dt.year, (dt.year+1)%100 if dt.month > 3 else dt.year-1,(dt.year)%100))
```

Okay, so let's break down your code:

`'{}-{}'.format(dt.year, (dt.year+1)%100 if dt.month > 3 else dt.year-1,(dt.year)%100)`

You have 2 `{}`s but 3(!) arguments:

- `dt.year`,
- `(dt.year+1)%100 if dt.month > 3 else dt.year-1`,
- `(dt.year)%100` (ignored because there are only 2 `{}`s)

As you can see, `if/else` works only for the middle argument.

What you want is to use this `if` on both arguments, so you either need to repeat the if or use parentheses to group things. But the grouping will result in a tuple, so you need to unpack the values with `*` (I mentioned grouping in the comments, but forgot about unpacking).

Solution with 2 ifs:

```
'{}-{}'.format(dt.year if dt.month > 3 else dt.year-1, 
               (dt.year+1)%100 if dt.month > 3 else (dt.year)%100)
```

As you can see, one comma - two arguments. Broke it down into two lines for readability.

Solution with one if and tuple unpacking:

```
'{}-{}'.format( *(dt.year, (dt.year+1)%100) if dt.month > 3 else *(dt.year-1,(dt.year)%100) )
```

Why unpacking? Because `'{}-{}'.format( ('2018','19') )` gets a single argument that is a tuple, not two arguments. It doesn't know what to do with it. `*` in front unpacks lists or tuples and provide them as normal arguments. - Read more about it [here in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It clears all the clouds from my head.

There is a correction for the answer, Need to include * only at the beginning in format say


`'{}-{}'.format(* (dt.year, (dt.year+1)%100) if dt.month > 3 else (dt.year-1,(dt.year)%100) )`